# Joining two convex nonintersecting polygons into one

Tags: python, computational-geometry

I need to join two convex, non-intersecting polygons into one joined covex polygon in way of minimisation of resulting area, like in picture below:[image] I'm seeking for an alhorithm doing this. I also would be appreciate if someone provide me with corresponding python implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are two non-intersecting polygons having say, m and n vertices respectively, then your problem can be thought of in this way:

Finding the convex polygon of the least area containing all of the m+n points. Having said this, check out the `QuickHull Algorithm` here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quickhull-algorithm-convex-hull/

Additionally you can also check out these algorithms.

Jarvis's Algorithm: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convex-hull-set-1-jarviss-algorithm-or-wrapping/

And, Graham's Scan: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convex-hull-set-2-graham-scan/

Hope this helps.

P.S. I think you can find the python implementations of these algorithms anywhere on the internet. :)

Comment: These suggestions do not exploit the fact that the points are already organized in two independent convex hulls.

Comment: What can be a possible way to do so?

Comment: Check my answer. Having two polygons rather than vertices in bulk amounts to saying that they are sorted. So you can spare the sorting step (traded for a simple merge).

Comment: I guess that's so.

Answer (score 4):

For an efficient solution, you can adapt the Monotone Chain method (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain) as follows:

- for both polygons, find the leftmost and rightmost sites (in case of ties, use the highest/lowest respectively);
- these sites split the polygons in two chains, that are ordered on X;
- merge the two upper and two lower chains with comparisons on X (this is a pass of mergesort);
- reject the reflex sites from the upper and lower chains, using the same procedure as in the monotone chain method (a variant of Graham's walk).

The total running time will be governed by

- n + m comparisons to find the extreme sites;
- n + m comparisons for the merge;
- n + m + 2 h LeftOf tests (signed area; h is the number vertices of the result).

Thus the complexity is O(n + m), which is not optimal but quite probably good enough for your purposes (a more sophisticated O(Log(n + m) solution is possible when the polygons do not overlap, but not worth the fuss for small polygon sizes).

[image]

In the example, the result of the merges are just the concatenation of the chains, but more complex cases can arise.

Final remark: if you keep all polygons as the concatenation of two monotone chains, you can spare the first step of the above procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the convex hull of both sets would work but the following approach is probably faster as it only needs to visit the polygons vertices in order:

1. Given polygons `P` and `Q`, pick from every one a vertex `p1` and `q1`.
2. Search in `Q` the vertex `q2` contiguous to `q1` such that the rotation from `p1-q1` to `p1-q2` is clockwise (this can be checked easyly using vector cross product).
3. Repeat until you reach a point `qk` whose two contiguous vertices in Q generate and anticlockwise rotation.
4. Now, invert the process traveling from `p1` across contigous vertices in P such that the rotation is anticlockwise until an extreme `pl` is found again.
5. Repeat from 2 until no more advance is possible. You have now two points `pm` and `pn` which are two the vertices where one side of the red area meets the black polygons in your drawing above.
6. Now repeat the algorithm again but changing the directions, from clockwise to anti-clockwise and vice-versa in order to find the vertices for the other side of the red area.
7. The only remaining work is generating the final polygon from the two red area sides already found and the segments from the polygons.